# I am trying to get a customer who has cancelled all orders , I am not able to do so

Tags: sql, mysql

```sql
SELECT
   oc.customer_id
  ,concat(oc.customer_fname,' ',oc.customer_lname) as Full_name
  ,oc.customer_email
  ,oc.customer_phone
  ,a.country
FROM online_customer oc
JOIN address a ON oc.address_id = a.address_id
WHERE oc.customer_id = (
  SELECT
    oh.customer_id
 FROM order_header oh
 WHERE oh.order_status = 'Cancelled'
)
GROUP BY oc.customer_id, concat(oc.customer_fname,' ', oc.customer_lname), oc.customer_email, oc.customer_phone, a.country;
```

There is a column in order_header table called Order_status  which has values "Shipped" ,"In process" and "Cancelled". Now I want a customer_id who has all orders as "Cancelled" in order_status. I am not able to get the logic right

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input, the expected output corresponding to the sample data, and more details about the logic you want to cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this logic by grouping the orders table by the `customer_id` then checking it has only one distinct `order_status`, and thats the single status (using max/min) is 'Canceled'

```
select oc.customer_id,concat(oc.customer_fname,' ',oc.customer_lname) as Full_name,oc.customer_email,oc.customer_phone,
a.country
from online_customer oc join address a on oc.address_id = a.address_id
where oc.customer_id=(select oh.customer_id
from order_header oh 
group by customer_id 
having count(distinct order_status) = 1 and max(order_status) = 'Cancelled')
group by oc.customer_id,concat(oc.customer_fname,' ',oc.customer_lname),oc.customer_email,oc.customer_phone,a.country;
```

Comment: It worked Thank you so much , you Sql pros are gods, Sql is my only weakness @Saar Levy

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked and the logic is as you expected! I'm sure your SQL skill  will get better over time. if my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer :) @Pree07

Comment: Done just now , Thank you again @Saar Levy